# How to set the ALT TAG on an image of our fan page?

Tags: facebook

I would simply like to know if its possible to give images an ALT tag on a Facebook fan page.

Here's an example of a basic fan page (not mine) that is posting space article updates:

http://www.facebook.com/universetoday

notice, the ALT tags are blank

http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l508/tmanran123/universe.gif

is there a way to fill those?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope its not possible to set alt tags in updates that is because facebook will pickup one image from the respective webpage and also resize it. This happens automatically and the user who is posting has no control over it
Regards
Nik

Comment: Man are you sure? We are loosing so much SEO value by losing that ALT tag.  i was hoping there was some property in the API somewhere that we're not seeing.