# Is it possible to retrieve alt text of facebook photos through API?

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Facebook uses [automatic alt tag text](https://code.facebook.com/posts/727262460626945/under-the-hood-facebook-accessibility/) for increasing accessibility, which is great.

Is there any way of accessing the `alt` tag of photos on Facebook using their API. I tried to look for that information on their [official API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo). But, I wasn't lucky to understand it much as I am a newbee to APIS.

So, my questions are two-fold?

- Is it possible to get the `alt` text using the API?
- if not, is their any other way of getting it programatically (preferably using **Python**?

*P.S*: My question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050821/how-to-set-the-alt-tag-on-an-image-of-our-fan-page) question, which is about setting the alt text using API. I am just looking for reading that information.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph API doesn't currently provide any way to access the `alt` text of uploaded photos. It does provide access to a photo's tagged users, events, and places, so if all your photos are tagged, you might be able to create similarly descriptive tags

[Facebook has also open sourced the software it uses to create these tags](https://code.facebook.com/posts/561187904071636/segmenting-and-refining-images-with-sharpmask/) (https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask) so you could also construct your own machine vision pipeline that would create similar tags.

Theoretically, you could also scrape photo pages from Facebook and pull the `alt` tag from there, but since this is against their Terms of Service, I do not recommend doing so.